# What would we call a hypothesis test that decreases in power as the sample size increases?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

In any given situation there is almost always more than one hypothesis test available. We use characteristics such as uniformly most powerful or locally most powerful, or being unbiased, to distinguish between tests and choose the best one.

I've stumbled upon an informal test that enjoys the following characteristic: as the sample size increases, the power decreases and the size increases. It is the so-called direct test used in some expert elicitation settings.  An example follows. Ask an expert for estimates and 90% coverage intervals for $n$ parameters of interest, and compare the claimed coverage 0.9 with the actual coverage (say, x/n).  If they are identical then the expert is well calibrated.  If they are not, then the expert is not well calibrated.

So in the case of n = 10 and 90% intervals, the null hypothesis that "the expert is not well calibrated" is rejected when the number of true values occurring within the experts intervals is in the rejection region, namely 9.

In the case of n = 100 and 90% intervals, the null hypothesis that "the expert is not well calibrated" is rejected when the random variable which is the number of true values occurring within the experts intervals is in the rejection region, namely 90.

Asymptotically, the power is zero and the size is 1. So, all else equal, we prefer to test with a smaller sample size.

This seems statistically distasteful to me but I'm unaware of any rules that preclude it from being used in a given situation.

Is there a name for such a characteristic? Lacking alternatives I lean towards "asymptotically powerless" but it's not clear that that is sufficient reason to reject it in low-sample settings.

Comment: The procedure you have described does not meet the minimum requirements of a classical hypothesis test.  Specifically, the user is unable to set the significance level $\alpha$ for the test which bounds the size of the test.  This occurs because you have stipulated a rejection region that is independent of any stipulated significance level.  I think this issue preempts any attempt to describe or name its properties

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I don't agree with your assessment.  The user can set the significance level by choosing a sample size.

Comment: I think you are conflating the significance level with the sample size --- these are two different things.  The sample size is fixed by observation, whereas the significance level is suppose to enter as a user choice which is applicable regardless of the sample size.

Comment: I don't think that I am.  In this instance, the user selects the sample size which in turn sets the size of the test. It's unusual in that the rejection region is a direct function of the sample size, but I don't think it invalidates the test in the way that you suggest.